# Android : Taking backup for media and messaging?

Tags: android, backup, media, message

What is the procedure to take backup of media and messaging? Is there any possible to do this. Anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

The messages are store in a DB in the following location:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
```